# Render a Blank Page with Ghostscript

Tags: ghostscript

How can I use ghostscript to create a blank page? I would like to do this when merging multiple PDFs together-- something like:

```
`gs -dNOPAUSE -o /path/to/output input1.pdf <blank-page-here> input2.pdf
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To spell out more explicitely what KenS suggested:

```
 gs                  \
   -o new.pdf        \
   -sDEVICE=pdfwrite \
   -f input1.pdf     \
   -c showpage       \
   -f input2.pdf     \
   -c showpage       \
   -f input3.pdf     \
   -c showpage
```

will insert an additional blank page into the `new.pdf` after the data of each `input{1,2,3}.pdf` has been processed.

Comment: Kurt, I can't count how many of your answers in SO have been extremely useful to me in the past few years. Thank you so much for taking the time to share your knowledge, it's very much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Just send some PostScript, the 'showpage' operator terminates a page if there's nothing on it, it will be blank.

You can either stick that in a file or use the -c -f switches.

Please note that the pdfwrite device does not merge files. It interprets the content of the input to create marking operations which are fed to the device. The device then takes action on those operations, for rendering devices it renders to a bitmap, in the case of pdfwrite it reassembles them into a PDF file.

So the output from your command line is not a 'merge' of the input files, its a brand new file whose only relationship with the input files is that the marks made on the page are the same.